$\sum_{n \geq 2} u_{n}(x)$ where $u_{n}(x) = \frac{\sin(nx)}{n^{x} + \ln(n)}$
I am examining the convergence of the series $\sum_{n \geq 2} u_{n}(x)$, where the term $u_{n}(x)$ is defined as follows:
\begin{equation}
u_{n}(x) = \frac{\sin(nx)}{n^{x} + \ln(n)} \quad \text{with} \quad x \in \mathbb{R}.
\end{equation}
For $x>0$, I have used Dirichlet's test to assess convergence, and I obtained conclusive results. Similarly, for $x=0$, the outcome is straightforward. However, when $x<0$, I find it challenging to determine whether the series converges or diverges, and I'm uncertain about the appropriate approach to address this case.

Can't you again use Dirichlet for $x<0$?

As $\sum_n \frac{\sin(nx)}{\ln(n)} <\infty$ by Dirichlet's test, it's sufficient to test the convergence of $u_n - \frac{\sin(nx)}{\ln(n)} $. But
$$v_n = u_n - \frac{\sin(nx)}{\ln(n)}  =  \frac{n^{x}\sin nx}{
\ln n (n^x + \ln n)} = \frac{\sin nx}{
\ln n (1+ n^{-x}\ln n)}.$$
where $\alpha = -x > 0$. As $n^{\alpha}\ln n$  is nondecrecasing, if follows that $\frac{1}{
\ln n (1+ n^{-x}\ln n)}$ is monotone and tends to $0$. Thus $v_n$ converges by Dirichlet's test. So $u_n$ converges also.
